# How can I make a reusable component for Material-UI Snackbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this Alert component to be used just to have a message that says "Successfully submitted" and I'm trying to use thin in a parent component. However, nothing shows in the parent component.

**AlertComponent**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Snackbar, Alert } from "@mui/material";

const AlertComponent = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success">
          Successfully Submitted!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AlertComponent;
```

**Parent Component**

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

       const onSubmit = async (data) => {
   //codes to submit the data
    setOpen(true); //trigger the alert component
   
  };
 
  return (
    <div>
      //form here to submit
      <AlertComponent open={open} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: accept props in AlertComponent , suggested snippet below:  
const AlertComponent = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(props.open);

Comment: just get the `open` porps in `AlertComponent`  , then remove its state and control Snackbar just with `ParentComponent` state that you passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although @Ghader Salehi commented already the solution but if anyone is not sure how to control the alert from parent here is the code.

AlertComponent.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Snackbar, Alert } from "@mui/material";
function AlertComponenet(props) {
  const { open, handleClose } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success">
          Successfully Submitted!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AlertComponenet;
```

Parent Component (In my code-sandbox I used App.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import AlertComponent from "./AlertComponent";

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Show Alert</button>
      <AlertComponent open={open} handleClose={handleClose} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: As improvement I suggest to put function `handleClose` in the `AlertComponent` and pass `setOpen` as parameter to argument:  

`<AlertComponent open={open} setOpen={setOpen} handleClose={handleClose} />`

This way, we don't have to rewrite `handleClose` to use `AlertComponent`